# Setting the style of UITableView section headers

Tags: uitableview, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm working with iOS 5 and have dynamically generated cells in a table (2 sections of 3 rows each).  Each section has a header that is also dynamically generated using the `titleForHeaderInSection` call.

I also have an image set as the background for the table that makes the default color of the section headers hard to read.  I haven't found a way to change the color of the section headers (or `shadow color`, `font`, `text size`, etc for that matter) either through the Storyboard interface or programmatically!  Please help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can modify the font size/color/etc by creating your own view for the section header using the method `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`

[There's an example of this technique here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180218150323/http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5172-font-size-color-tableview-header.html#Comment_75192)

Comment: Thanks!  That took care of it!

Answer (score 37):

This also works in iOS5+. It applies to all of the section headers and footers in the tableview and suited my needs.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:8]];
}
```

Dan

Comment: Just what I was looking for to modify the appearance of my table sections defined in a storyboard, without needing to implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use appearance proxy on UILabel. Even if you works, it could break with any revision.

Comment: In Swift 2, you can get the `UIAppearance` instance by using the static `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses(_:)` method. E.g., `UILabel.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self]).textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`

Answer (score 13):

#### The actual easiest way

If you're not doing too much modification, for example just changing the font or colors:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *tableViewHeaderFooterView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    tableViewHeaderFooterView.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12.0f];
    tableViewHeaderFooterView.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.27f green:0.27f blue:0.27f alpha:1.0f];
    tableViewHeaderFooterView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.87f green:0.87f blue:0.87f alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: Having issues with this when my section's text goes for several lines: the view's height does not adjust accordingly. Any idea how to fix this easily?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:

Comment: This is by far the simplest way to do it.  Kudos!!

Answer (score 7):

The `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` class implements a reusable view that can be placed at the top or bottom of a table section. You use headers and footers to display additional information for that section.

Availability:  iOS (6.0 and later)

Example:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: I prefer this solution MUCH more than the accepted one, because you don't have to worry to excatly "rebuild" the header-view if you just want to change background-color or text-color. And it DOES work in iOS 7 if you use `setTextColor`. But if you want to customize the view more than just exchange some colors, using a complete new view - as the accepted answer suggests - might be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

### The easiest way to get a custom section header - use a cell!

Very Similar to the technique used for

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can create an instance of a cell prototype that you provide. If your cell includes an outlet for a label, you can set it before returning it:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    SessionTableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SessionSectionHeader"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SessionTableViewCell alloc]
               initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:@"SessionSectionHeader"];
    }
    cell.myLabel.text = myTitles[section];
    return cell;
}
```

Note that @"SessionSectionHeader" is the identifier in the storyboard for our cell prototype.

HTH!

Comment: Yeah, unless you need the section headers to be displayed as they are by default (that is fixed on top even if the first section cell is offscreen).

Comment: This also breaks accessibility, since section headers are no longer identifiable.